# While adding startForeground() to a service two notifications are created instead of one

Tags: android, service, notifications

So I've created a service and it works great. All it does is just count. I have a custom class that handles the hassle of using notifications. This class has a getNotification which, obviously, returns the notification it uses. Everything worked great but I've got to make my service to run on foreground (it syncs some important data to the app which must not be interrupted until it finishes) Right now when I'm adding startForeground I add my notification and an id which leaves it like this.
startForeground(1337, notification);

Problem I have is that the first notify() I do is, for some reason, independent from the others notifications. So when I make this run it creates two notifications. The first one is stuck on the first update which has a title called "Zilean" and it's content says "Counting". The other one updates perfectly. I've notice that if startForeground is ran with an id of 0 (startForeground(0,notification)) then this problem gets fixed, but if I kill the activity the notification dies. Doesn't happen when the id <> 0.

I had this problem for too long so I'm using a dummy service which only counts. I want to know that if the activity dies due to the user or just because android decided to delete it's memories, then the service will keep going.

```
// onStartCommand
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // NOTIFICATION SECTION
    NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this);

    notificationManagerClass = new SBNNotification(mNotifyManager,
            mBuilder, true, 1, false, "Zilean",
            "Initiating Counter", false);
    notificationManagerClass.notificate();



        final Notification notification = notificationManagerClass.getNotification();
    notification.flags = flags;
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    startForeground(1337, notification);


    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask () {
        int i=0;
        @Override
        public void run() {

            notificationManagerClass.setContentTitle("Contando");
            notificationManagerClass.setContentText(String.valueOf(i));
            notificationManagerClass.notificate();
            i++;
            Log.e("HOLAAA", String.valueOf(i));
        }}, 0, 1000);

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

So.. what I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved, my error was that the notification id wasnt the same as the startForeground id I was passing (1337)

Edit: It's important to note that the notification id and the service id must not be 0, else it'll blend with the main activity thread